# Continuous onto Map from semi open interval to open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous surjective map from $[a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ ? if not them why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t>0$ be fixed, $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{t-x})$ maps $[0,t)$ onto $(-t,t)$. Then apply proper transposition we get $[a,b)\to (-t,t)$and apply scaling.

Comment: if i take t=1 then range is not (-1,1)  but its [-1,1].

Comment: actually there is no surjective continuous map. But why?

Comment: @YOGESH If you take $t=1$, $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{1}{1-x})$, for $x\in[0,1)$. Note $x$ can't be $1$. So $|f(x)|\le x<1$. Why the range is $[-1,1]$?

Comment: if i take t=1 the as x tend to 1 from left then 1-x will tend to zero ans so function will ossicaltes between -1 to 1 that why...

Comment: @YOGESH But after multiplying $x$? Can you reach $1$?

Comment: afret multiplicatin by x its again oscillate ..

Comment: @YOGESH but the value of $f$ can't be $1$ or $-1$

Comment: it will be 1 as well as -1 infinite times...

Comment: @YOGESH may you name one?

Comment: mean?? my name?

Comment: ok i think you are right....i will think again...again..

Comment: Let f : R → R be a continuous function.Then can the image of [0,1) be (0,1) under f?

Comment: actually i forgot that f is continuous on R

Comment: OK OK  i got the answer it can not as if i add one more point [0,1) i.e. 1 in it then it become compact, but range can not be compact by adding its image. Thanks ...

Comment: its true only when f is continuous on R. You are right....

Comment: @YOGESH I am glad it solves your problem.